# Excel - Using condtional formatting in a count down of the date

Tags: microsoft-excel, conditional-formatting

So i am using Excel Mac 2008, i want a formula where i enter a date and if the date is less than 5 days from today, it turns bold and red. can anyone help me figure this out? 
I have a formula that counts down the days `=E2-TODAY()` but I'm not sure if this can be incorporated. Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

In Excel 2007 this worked for the Conditional Formatting formula.

```
=(TODAY()-$A2)<5
```

To only include the five days leading up to today (if you have dates in the future):

```
=AND((TODAY()-$A2)<5,(TODAY()-$A2)>-1)
```